# Why is it that privileges are lost when the reputation decreases but badges are retained?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, serial-voting, privileges

For reviewing "Low Quality Posts" and "Suggested Edits", one needs at least 1000 reps, which I had until a few days back. Somebody(-ies) unupvoted my answers making my rep to decrease by 420 in a single day, which brought my rep **back to below 1k**. Now, I am deprived of the privileges.

But the unupvotes did not cause the Nice-answer badges to disappear.

So, my questions are:

- why the privileges are gone while badges are still there?
- If the answers again gain 10 votes, will I earn another nice-answer badge for the same answer?

Also, the best the answer to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting) says:

> The motivation behind -1 for downvote is to put emphasis on **up-voting or not voting at all**. This way, down votes will carry more weight and it will also prevent users from abusing the system by down-voting excessively.

So, to stop users from playing games with the voting system, why not enact a -1 for unupvotes too?

Comment: Not sure why this question has been down-voted!?

Comment: @Kaveh Because of the feature that was requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an SE rule privileges are strictly bound to the users reputations (mods being an exception):

> [If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Badges once awarded are to be kept by the user and (almost) never taken aways they stay with the user. Except for tag badges.

> Most badges a user can earn don't have any effect on site functionality; they are simply signs of accomplishment and bragging rights. A user's abilities are governed not by his badges, but by his [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

> The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating. Behavior that qualifies as "heinous" is defined by devs on a case-by-case basis

[Source.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/221866)

As for the massive unupvote you have garnered, it definitely falls under the category of serial upvoting and is [*against* the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199952/221866) and is definitely wrong:

> The votes are un-upvotes, but they are voting behavior non the less. And they are targeted at specific users, not the content.
>
> As such this goes against the rules - it is not allowed in any shape or form.

---

> If the answers again gain 10 votes, will I earn another nice-answer badge for the same answer?

No. It doesn't. Speaking through personal experience.

> So, to stop users from playing games with vote-unvote-vote-unvote, why not enact a -1 for un-upvote too?

This, would be outrageously wrong! Imagine X gave an bad answer and Y downvoted it. The vote got locked after 5mins (preventing unupvote). Then the answer got edited (by X or someone else). The edit actually improved the answer to a level that now it doesn't deserve a downvote but isn't good enough to deserve an upvote. So Y decided to remove the downvote. Handing Y a -1 for that what be wrong altogether. That is the very reason the vote are unlocked after the post is edited because editing could make the post bad or it could make it better and that's why Y is given the right to reconsider his/her vote.

*What's bad is **abusing** this system*

Comment: well, there could be at least some functionality to prevent serial un-upvoting of x's answers by y, because the situation in the last paragraph cannot happen to more than 10 answers of X in a single day. .. given the fact that 26 answers of mine have been edited (most of the edits are capitalization/decap only) by a particular user within one single day, i think it is pretty safe to assume that the edits were made **IN ORDER TO** be able to un-upvote.

Comment: I agree there should be. And hence there is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199946/221866) feature-request (also linked in the answer).